# Origine dell'espressione “FAMME NU PIACERE VA' JETTATTE A MMARE”

Tags: regional, phrase-origin

Vorrei sapere qual è l'origine di questa frase.

FAMME NU PIACERE VA' JETTATTE A MMARE!

Comment: Non è un'espressione italiana (sospetto sia napoletana ma sono molto scarso a distinguere fra di loro i dialetti meridionali), ma credo voglia dire *Fammi un piacere, va' a buttarti in mare*. Non credo ci sia un'origine più profonda del significato letterale, ma potrei sbagliarmi (magari proviene da un film?).

Comment: It sounds a bit Sicilian. It means: "Do me a favor and go jump in a lake [the sea]". (Sorry but my Italian is not good enough to post here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Senza entrare nel dettaglio è una frase di origine campana (comunemente e generalmente raggruppando i dialetti della zona in dialetto napoletano).
Letteralmente la frase tradotta in italiano è:

> Fammi un piacere, va' a buttarti a mare.

L'espressione è comunemente usata da una persona che, in risposta ad una affermazione assurda, esagerata, o che in generale provoca ributtanza, la esclama per esprimere la propria contrarietà.

Non necessariamente è utilizzata in modo totalmente negativo, in quanto tra amici si può usare quando in un primo momento non si crede ad un evento improbabile.

> Mario: “Luigi, lo sai che ho pescato un tonno di 5kg?”
>
> Luigi: “Mario, *famme nu piacere, va' jettatte a mmare*!” (Non dire assurdità)

Comment: In napoletano mi suona molto meglio *va' te jett''a mmare*. va' e jettate sono due imperativi e, come in italiano dovrebbero essere separati da una virgola. Jettatte, poi, è un passato remoto (gettò), quindi non concorda col resto della frase.